# Add buttons to mat-tab-group

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am brand new to Angular 2/4 and have been enjoying the Material Design components (https://material.angular.io).  I have a simple SPA which uses a tab group for switching between dynamic views.  I have a plus button for adding more tabs and each tab can deleted itself.

My question is whether the mat-tab-group can be altered to contain the "plus" button in the upper bar (where the tabs appear).  Right now it sits in a div beside the mat-tab-group div, and thus takes up 20px along the whole right side of my web-page, which does not look terribly nice.

Comment: Could you use CSS to change the button's style to  `position:relative` and set `left: -30px` ?

Answer (score 45):

One approach would be to add another disabled tab with no content and attach the click event to a button in the tab label.

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Tab 1 Content</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Tab 2 Content</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab disabled>
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
            <button mat-icon-button (click)="someFn()">
                <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

The only odd thing is the width of the tab label. I haven't been able to figure out how to reduce that specific one.

Comment: How to select the latest created tab?

Comment: I haven't tested it but looking at the `MatTabGroup` API, there is an input called `selectedIndex` that you may be able to set on that component. For example, `<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="1">` where 1 would be replaced with a dynamic way to retrieve the new tab index.

Comment: A trick by disabling is cool. Without this I had problems that tab with "+" was displayed, but in fact there was no data there. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to make the button in the disabled tab, not look disabled?

Comment: Any other way for adding `button` in `mat-tab`? I am using angular material

Comment: As i have `nested tabs` also so it not doing exactly what i want.

Answer (score 5):

Did that in my styles.css to remove the disabled style and reduce the size of the tab:

```
my-component .mat-tab-labels :last-child.mat-tab-label {
  min-width: 0;
  padding: 0 12px;
  color: unset;
  opacity: unset;
}
```

Where "my-component" is the html selector of your component.

look like this :
[tabs with add button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI4Gf.png)

Comment: I got it to work using `my-component ::ng-deep .mat-tab-labels :last-child.mat-tab-label`

Comment: you can add a custom class to the tab if you don't want to override the material one :
<mat-tab disabled labelClass="logo">

Comment: do the .mat-tab-labels still existe ?

Comment: @Ollie do the .mat-tab-labels still exist ? i'm A NEWBIE in angular

Answer (score 2):

As [Jared answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47042261/add-buttons-to-mat-tab-group#answer-47194002). Although, you can change the width of last tab by setting [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) to `None` in your component.

**Typescript code:**

```ts
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ....
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Now you can style your last tab

**Component CSS:**

```css
.mat-tab-label:last-child {
  opacity: 1;
  min-width: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me

Answer (score 0):

here it is another solution

..ts

```
  @ViewChild(MatTabGroup) tabGroup!: MatTabGroup;

  onSelectedTabChange(tabIndex: number) {
    console.log('Selected tab index: ', tabIndex);
    if (tabIndex === $INDEX_OF_BUTTON) {
      this.tabGroup.selectedIndex = 0;
    }
  }
```

..html

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedIndexChange)="onSelectedTabChange($event)">
    <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Tab 1 Content</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Tab 2 Content</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab>
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
            <button mat-icon-button (click)="someFn()">
                <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```